# Custom HTML form POST values to Drupal form

Tags: drupal

On my main website, built in Drupal, I have a Drupal form (using module) to gather Newsletter subscribers.

On another website, built in HTML, the same Newsletter form needs to be shown and any submission on the form will POST the values to my Drupal website.

I copied the source code (HTML) of the Drupal form to my HTML website but the values are not submitting to Drupal form when I clicked submit. It just showed a fresh form on Drupal.

Are there any way to submit values from HTML form to Drupal's?

Comment: Drupal forms have CSRF protection, you'll need to get around that.

Answer (score 0):

As Clive mentioned, the CSRF protection prevents you from doing that.

Another way you could go about solving this problem is using an iframe into your Drupal site. It'd take some tweaking of the display to make fit your other site, but it would allow a visitor to submit data to the Drupal form while still viewing the other site.